# Android PrintDocumentAdapter remove/hide save as pdf option

Tags: android, printing, android-print-manager

When trying to print pdf from android application, I want to hide/remove/disable save as pdf feature of PrintDocumentAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have control over that, short of building your own custom Android firmware and installing it on your own hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Select an item to print from your Android phone. Select the printer you've added for your default printer and then print the item. Next time you need to print something, the default printer will come up automatically and the Save as PDF will be secondary.

In other words, whatever you choose most (print or save) will come up the next time. Hope this helps. Worked for me.